# Co-ordinate rotations

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, coordinate-systems, rotation

I need help transforming a magnetic field vector from one co-ordinate system to another. I have the components of the Earth's magnetic field in a co-ordinate system with z facing radially into the Earth and x pointing North. I need to convert that into a new co-ordinate system where z is parallel to the Earth's axis and y points towards the Sun (so that x would point tangent to the Earth's orbit). I wanted to characterise this by a rotation about the x axis to account for latitude using the rotation matrix:

$\left[ \begin{array}( 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ 0 & \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \end{array} \right]$

and then to use a second rotation matrix around z to account for the time of day by rotating by an angle $\theta = 2\pi - \omega (t \mod 24)$ where $\omega$ is in rad/hour. But I've discovered that rotation matrices don't commute, so this strategy doesn't seem to work. What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy is fine (though I haven't carefully checked if your rotations are correct). Since rotations don't commute, you need to be careful to apply them in the correct order. You say that your rotation about the x-axis, let's call it $R$, followed by your rotation around the z-axis (be careful whether it's around the old or the new z-axis!), let's call it $S$, is the final rotation you want. So anytime you have a vector $\mathbf{v}$, the rotation you need to apply is $SR\mathbf{v}$ and not $RS\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know which order I should apply them in. I can't seem to get my head around why applyng the rotations requires the correct order, even though I've confirmed that it's true.

Comment: Well, you apply the first one first and the second one second. You've already figured out the order in your post; like I said, you apply the x-axis rotation first and the z-axis rotation second. Remember that you write them backwards because matrices act on the right. *Why* rotations don't commute, that's a much more profound question.